# panda read_csv() converting imaginary to real

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

After calling a file using pandas by this two lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('PN_lateral_n_eff.txt', header=None)
df.columns = ["effective_index"]
```

here is my output:

```
                         effective_index
0  2.568393573877396+1.139080496494329e-006i
1  2.568398351899841+1.129979376397734e-006i
2  2.568401556986464+1.123872317134941e-006i
```

after that, i can not use the numpy to convert it into a real number. Because, panda dtype was object. I tried this:

```
np.real(df, dtype = float)
```

> TypeError: real() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Any way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read complex numbers from file with NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659818/how-to-read-complex-numbers-from-file-with-numpy)

Comment: `np.real` docs say it only takes one argument.  Why did you specify a `dtype`?

Comment: I tried with one only by slicing the array. It didnt work unfortunately

Comment: What's the `dtypes` for this dataframe?

Comment: 'object' always

Comment: And that 'complex' number, is that really complex or is it a string?   `(2+3.12j)` is the normal Python display format.

Comment: I guess the complex number is a string while panda is reading that from txt

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `astype(complex)` works with Numpy arrays of strings, but not with Pandas Series of objects:

```
cmplx = df['effective_index'].str.replace('i','j')\ # Go engineering
                             .values\               # Go NumPy
                             .astype('str')\        # Go string
                             .astype(np.complex)    # Go complex
#array([ 2.56839357 +1.13908050e-06j,  2.56839835 +1.12997938e-06j,
#        2.56840156 +1.12387232e-06j])
df['effective_index'] = cmplx # Go Pandas again
```