# how to load 4-bit data into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, complex-numbers

I have a binary data file that contains 8-bit complex samples--i.e. 4 bits and 4 bits for imaginary and real (Q and I) components from MSB to LSB.

How can I get this data into a numpy complex number array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no support for doing 8-bit complex numbers (4-bit real, 4-bit imaginary).
As such the following method is a good way to efficiently read them into separate numpy arrays for complex and imaginary.

```
values = np.fromfile("filepath", dtype=int8)
real = np.bitwise_and(values, 0x0f)
imag = np.bitwise_and(values >> 4, 0x0f)
```

then if you want one complex array,

```
signal = real + 1j * imag
```

There are more ways for converting two real arrays to a complex array here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2598820/1131073

---

If the values are 4-bit ints that could be negative (i.e. two's complement applies), you can use arithmetic bit shifting to separate out the two channels correctly:

```
real = (np.bitwise_and(values, 0x0f) << 4).astype(np.int8) >> 4
imag = np.bitwise_and(values, 0xf0).astype(int) >> 4
```

Comment: The `bitwise_and` operations are actually unnecessary. `real = values << 4 >> 4` and `imag = values >> 4` handles the sign and type correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python) for reading data in one byte at a time, this should work:

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(1)
        real = byte >> 4
        imag = byte & 0xF
        # Store numbers however you like
```

Comment: So there's no way to do it with memmap or anything like that?

Comment: Then would it not be more efficient to do: `real = np.bitwise_and(a, 0x0f); imag = np.bitwise_and(a >> 4, 0x0f);` where `a` is the array of bytes from the file?

Comment: @B-Brock: Yes, your suggestion would be much more efficient.

Comment: @B-Brock Definitely. I was going for a more demonstrative example rather than something advanced but fast. But you're definitely correct.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your input!--it implied what I wanted to know :)