# Assigning real and imaginary parts of a complex array from two arrays containing the two parts - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, complex-numbers

I have two arrays, `field_in_k_space_REAL` and `field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY`, that contain, respectively, the real and imaginary parts of an array of complex numbers, `field_in_k_space_TOTAL`, which I would like to create. Why does the following assignment not work, producing the error

```
AttributeError: attribute 'real' of 'numpy.generic' objects is not writable


field_in_k_space_TOTAL = zeros(n, complex)
for i in range(n):
    field_in_k_space_TOTAL[i].real = field_in_k_space_REAL[i]
    field_in_k_space_TOTAL[i].imag = field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY[i]
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear; what is confusing you? Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2598734/3001761

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion by @Ffisegydd (and by @jonsharpe in a comment) are good ones.  See if that works for you.

Here, I'll just point out that the `real` and `imag` attributes of the *array* are writeable, and the vectorized assignment works, so you can simplify your code to

```
field_in_k_space_TOTAL = zeros(n, complex)

field_in_k_space_TOTAL.real = field_in_k_space_REAL
field_in_k_space_TOTAL.imag = field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign the specific real and imaginary parts of a numpy element. You'd have to create an intermediate value and then assign it to `field_total`, for example:

```
for i in range(n):
    x = field_in_k_space_REAL[i] + field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY[i]
    field_in_k_space_TOTAL[i] = x
```

This will be slow and cumbersome though. Instead, why don't you just add the two arrays together and make use of vectorisation? I can *promise* you, it'll be much quicker.

```
import numpy as np

# Note: dropping the long names.

field_real = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30])
field_imag = np.array([0j, 1j, 2j, 3j])

field_total = field_real + field_imag

print(field_total)
# [  0.+0.j  10.+1.j  20.+2.j  30.+3.j]
```

In the case where `field_imag` is an array of real numbers that you want to convert to imaginary (as in your original example) then the following code will work (thanks to jonrsharpe for the comment).

```
field_real = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30])
field_imag = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])

field_total = field_real + (field_imag * 1j)
```

Comment: Or if `field_imag` isn't already imaginary, `field_real + (field_imag * 1j)`

Answer (score 1):

You simply do

```
field_in_k_space_TOTAL = field_in_k_space_REAL + 1j*field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY
```

It is hard to do anything simpler. :)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your data types are compatible, you can do:

```
field_in_k_space_TOTAL = np.hstack((field_in_k_space_REAL[:,None], field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY[:,None])).ravel().view(np.complex)
```