# How to parametrize a complex number in terms of variables in python

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I want to represent a complex number / an array of complex numbers as `c = a + bj`, where a and b are two variables. I know I can do `c = a + b*(1j)` or `c = complex(a, b)`. But if a and b are arrays, then `c = complex(a, b)` won't work. Is `c = a + b*(1j)` the best way?

Comment: Add a programming language tag.

Comment: And are you using numpy?

Comment: In that case you're looking for [python - Numpy: Creating a complex array from 2 real ones? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598734/numpy-creating-a-complex-array-from-2-real-ones)

Comment: @user202729 Thank you for the suggestion in the link. I think that's a good solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy: Creating a complex array from 2 real ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598734/numpy-creating-a-complex-array-from-2-real-ones)

Comment: @user202729 Yes, thank you!