# Optimization to find minimum of function containing complex numbers

Tags: python, optimization, complex-numbers

I'm trying to use Python to find the value of a vector z that corresponds to the minimum of a function.  z could be either rectangular, z = a+b*j or polar form, z = magnitude,phase. I've tried to input it a few ways and currently have it as z = complex(cwx,cwy) in the code block below.  I used meshgrid in an attempt to create the space of possible vectors over which to evaluate the function.

The function contains z and other complex numbers (vectors in polar form that I'm converting to rectangular).  The function evaluates to a scalar so there should be some vector that results in a minima.  Hoping someone can point me in the right direction as I'm new to optimization and floundering so far :| Is there an optimization function that plays nicely with complex numbers?

```
from math import radians
from cmath import rect
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

# input variables, to be obtained via GUI
w1 = 0.5
w2 = 0.5
a1m = 53
a1p = 280
a2m = 46
a2p = 245
s11m = 1.8
s11p = 338
s21m = 1.1
s21p = 332
cwm_max = 500

f = lambda z: (w1*abs(rect(a1m,radians(a1p)) + complex(cwx,cwy) / rect(s11m,radians(s11p))) +
                w2*abs(rect(a2m,radians(a2p)) + complex(cwx,cwy) / rect(s21m,radians(s21p))))

# create a grid of potential vectors wrapping from 0 to 360 degress with max amplitude = cwm_max:
cwx, cwy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-cwm_max,cwm_max,200),np.linspace(-cwm_max,cwm_max,200))

# opt.minimze requires a guess argument
guess = np.array([0, 200])
sol = opt.minimize(f, guess)
print(sol)
```

It doesn't like my use of complex(cwx,cwy) in the function.  Thinks I want to input a scalar?

```
f = lambda z: (w1*abs(rect(a1m,radians(a1p)) + complex(cwx,cwy) / rect(s11m,radians(s11p))) +
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

and opt.minimize() doesn't look to be the best tool for the job as that is throwing a variety of Traceback issues.

---

Brute force alternative with nested loops did the trick:

```
cwm_max = 500 
dim = 1200 
mag_sum = 1000*np.ones((dim,dim)) 

cwx = np.linspace(-cwm_max,cwm_max,dim)
cwy = np.linspace(-cwm_max,cwm_max,dim)

for p in range(dim):
    for q in range(dim):
        mag_sum[p,q] = (w1 * abs(rect(a1m, radians(a1p)) + complex(cwx[p],cwy[q]) / rect(s11m, radians(s11p)))+ w2 * abs(rect(a2m, radians(a2p)) + complex(cwx[p],cwy[q]) / rect(s21m, radians(s21p))))

# rectangular to polar
def polar_deg(z):
    """expects a single complex number in cartesian form (a+bj),
    returns mag & phase (degrees, 0 to 360)"""
    mag, phase_r = cmath.polar(z)
    phase_d = math.degrees(phase_r)
    if phase_d < 0:
        phase_d += 360
    return mag, phase_d

a,b = np.unravel_index(mag_sum.argmin(), mag_sum.shape)
cwz = complex(cwx[a],cwy[b])
cwm, cwp = polar_deg(cwz)
```

Comment: What does "minima" mean for complex numbers?  Does it mean "closest to (0+0i)"?

Comment: The function f evaluates to a scalar so minima would be closest to 0.

Comment: OK, here's another.  Your function accepts `z` but does not use it.  That makes it a constant, right?

Comment: The cause of the error is that the Python `complex` type (which is not numpy) cannot handle numpy arrays.  [Numpy: Creating a complex array from 2 real ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598734/numpy-creating-a-complex-array-from-2-real-ones)

Comment: Oh, I see.  Well, I think I found a brute force way of doing it with nested loops.  It's not pretty but it gets the job done.  Was hoping to find a built-in optimization function and got fixated on that path.  The nested loops will have to do.

Comment: Nested loops solution added to the original post above.

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question - that's good, but for the question to be useful on StackOverflow, it would be good to put the solution in an answer you can write below your own question, and to then accept your own answer, so that the question no longer appears as unanswered.

Comment: Done, thanks for explaining the Stack Overflow process.  Wasn't aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force alternative with nested loops did the trick:

```
cwm_max = 500 
dim = 1200 
mag_sum = 1000*np.ones((dim,dim)) 

cwx = np.linspace(-cwm_max,cwm_max,dim)
cwy = np.linspace(-cwm_max,cwm_max,dim)

for p in range(dim):
    for q in range(dim):
        mag_sum[p,q] = (w1 * abs(rect(a1m, radians(a1p)) + complex(cwx[p],cwy[q]) / rect(s11m, radians(s11p)))+ w2 * abs(rect(a2m, radians(a2p)) + complex(cwx[p],cwy[q]) / rect(s21m, radians(s21p))))

# rectangular to polar
def polar_deg(z):
    """expects a single complex number in cartesian form (a+bj),
    returns mag & phase (degrees, 0 to 360)"""
    mag, phase_r = cmath.polar(z)
    phase_d = math.degrees(phase_r)
    if phase_d < 0:
        phase_d += 360
    return mag, phase_d

a,b = np.unravel_index(mag_sum.argmin(), mag_sum.shape)
cwz = complex(cwx[a],cwy[b])
cwm, cwp = polar_deg(cwz)
```